# div is not at new line when previous div uses position relative

Tags: html, css

I have two div tags in a parent div(class of banner)

The first one(class of logo-section) uses position relative

The problem that the second one(class of greeting
) is not at new line like usually. Here is the code:

```css
.banner {
  margin: 0 100px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(../images/homepage_header_background.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.banner .logo-section {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.banner .logo-section #logo-bg {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 3px #888888;
          box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 3px #888888;
}

.banner .logo-section #logo {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

.banner .greeting p {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
        <div class="logo-section">
            <p id="logo-bg"></p>
            <img id="logo" src="./images/ads-logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="greeting">
            <p>Greetings from Viet Nam</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Because parent is flex container, and it's supposed to make child items as columns

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I use flex container to center element, so is there any way to make it at new line ?

Comment: If you want to center the banner, one option is to wrap the banner element in something else, center that as you are then remove the flex from the banner element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `flex`, setting `flex-direction: column;` for the class banner will break text to new line.

```css
.banner {
  margin: 0 100px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(../images/homepage_header_background.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner .logo-section {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.banner .logo-section #logo-bg {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 3px #888888;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 3px #888888;
}

.banner .logo-section #logo {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.banner .greeting p {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="logo-section">
    <p id="logo-bg"></p>
    <img id="logo" src="./images/ads-logo.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="greeting">
    <p>Greetings from Viet Nam</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's at new line but the parent does not center its child element anymore

Comment: @HuỳnhĐứcBùi I have added `align-items: center;` hope this works